# How do you show $f(x) = 1 - a + ax - x^a \geq 0$ if $a \in (0, 1)$ and $x \geq 0$?

Tags: inequality

How do you show $f(x) = 1 - a + ax - x^a \geq 0$ if $a \in (0, 1)$ and $x \geq 0$?

True for $x = 0$ but for $x \neq 0$ wts. $ax - x^a \geq a - 1$ ?

Any help would be apprecaited thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

For $ x>0$
$$f'(x)=a(1-e^{(a-1)\ln(x)})$$

$$x>1\implies f'(x)>0$$
$$x<1\implies f'(x)<0$$
$$f'(1)=0\; \; f(1)=0$$

$ f $ is continuous at $ x=0$, with $ f(0)=1-a>0$.

$ f$ attains its absolute minimum at $ x=1$.